# Search multiple search engines with a single keyword at the same time in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, search-engines

I want to search multiple websites at once by using a keyword trigger in Google Chrome. I am trying to achieve this with Javascript as described in [this topic over at mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=334850).

This is the code that supposedly works in Firefox:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s'));void(window.open('http://www.altavista.com/web/results?q=%s'))
```

I have tried to insert this code into the "URL with %s in place of query" (right click address bar -> Edit search engines) but nothing happens when I invoke it. Is it possible to get this to work this way or another in Chrome? I would prefer to achieve this without extensions. I would appreciate a comment if it is impossible. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly what you were looking for, but it is quite helpful. [Search Center](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ndfplmdnbnefomnjiknbpejdceedhdmf) which is an addon to Chrome, lets you search many sites an you can add your own too.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for. No more copy pasting of search terms across search sites.

Comment: This website (http://www.searchonce.net/) also useful too..

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried to insert this code [...] but nothing happens when I invoke it.

When you use a search engine from the omnibox, it just transforms the query string into an URL. That works well with actual URLs, but it can fail with `javascript:`.

You will be able to use this custom search if you're in a tab displaying a normal website, but not if you're looking at the *New Tab* or *Settings* page, for example. The reason is that Chrome disables `javascript:` URLs in any form (direct invocation from omnibox, custom search, bookmark, etc.) for the internal `chrome://` pages ([source](http://codereview.chromium.org/7748022)).

This is done for security reasons, since these pages often contain sensitive information (e.g., *New Tab* contains links to the most visited websites), and JavaScript could access and divulge that information.

> Is it possible to get this to work this way or another in Chrome? I would prefer to achieve this without extensions.

I don't think that there's a straightforward way of achieving this, as any attempt to automatically open several tabs from a common HTML page will result in several new *windows* (unless this is desired).

The best way to solve this would probably be an extension.

Further options:

- Keep using your existing approach.

  Just make sure you don't open a new tab before you search. Since your custom search doesn't modify the existing tab, you might get used to that.
- "Extend" your search with a bookmark.

  Leave Google (for example) as your default search and create the following bookmark:

  ```
  Name: Extend Google search
  URL:  javascript:var q=document.location.search.match(/[?&][pq]=(.*?)(&|$)/)[1];window.open('http://www.altavista.com/web/results?q='+q);window.open('http://www.bing.com/search?q='+q);void(0)
  ```

  Clicking the bookmark after performing a Google search will search in all other engines.

Answer (score 1):

[Big Search](https://github.com/garywill/bigSearch) is an addon with the feature you need. It's cross-browser, for both Chrome and Firefox.

| Screenshots |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Extension UI | Context selection search | Use on web without install | Mobile UI (web) |
| [image: screenshot_en] | [image: screenshot_context] | [image: screenshot_web] | [image: screenshot_mobile] |

[Watch demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hn5BkviAyvQ)

Comparing to other similar tools, this tool uses JSON for search engines database (both built-in and user-defined), so it has strong flexibility in engine data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to your issue [here](http://openworld.orgfree.com/projects/newsearch/newsearch.htm). 
Pretty simple extension that you could change to any search engine.

Also, if you download the source and change the popup.html file to include the code `checked='checked'` next to each of the terms you would like to default, so you wouldn't have to check the four boxes yourself.

For example change:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='search' value="1" id='google' />Google<br />
```

to:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='search' value="1" id='google' />Google<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

See
[QuickSearch Is A Multi-Search Engine Extension For Google Chrome](http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/search-many-search-engines-google-chrome.html),
which describes the extension named QuickSearch, which brings the ability to quickly perform searches via different sites.

This article also comments :

> Though **Chrome supports keyword based multi-search** engine capabilities
>   `(Options > Basics > Default search > Manage`) which enable users to
>   search on different sites right from the omnibar, still, I would
>   prefer this simple extension.

[image]